# How to develop multi paint (on maps)

Tags: wpf, maps

I want to develop a multi-paint: An application, which each user can paint route on a map, save the route, and in the end all the saved routes will be "merged" into one big picture (like layers in photoshop)

How should I save the routes? List of pixels to be drawn? Save it to picture (with transparent background?)

The application will be developed in WPF on bing maps (on touch device).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to save the latitude and longitude values of the route points, perhaps in a [LocationCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.locationcollection.aspx), which is part of the [Bing Maps WPF Control API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872901.aspx).

Simply saving the pixels wouldn't work when you want to be able to zoom the map.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I have another problem:

I want to draw when the mouse is dragged, I wanted to use this guide: [link](http://ngjon.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/interactive-drawing-on-the-silverlight-map-control/) But I can't find the mouseTap event on the Map control. I guess it's only avaliable in the Silverlight version. How Should I trace the mouse?

Comment: That should be another question.